# How do I test iOS microphone use on the simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

How do I test the microphone in my IOs simulator? I don't think it records through the built in audio at the top of my Mac screen, which I understand.

Which of these options would work?

1.Plug a real microphone into my laptop

2.Export the app into my Iphone <- I don't know how to do this yet

3.Download some library that will use the built in audio on my macbook screen <- I saw a youtube video about this months ago but I can't find it now.

I appreciate any feedback. I'm asking this now to avoid programming strings of code that I cannot test.

Thank you

-Samuel

Comment: It will, sorta, record audio fed through the earphone jack, using an iPhone mike adapter cable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The built in microphones should work with the iOS Simulator.

Comment: I have a USB microphone, I'll try using both methods after quickly programming some code. Thank you

Comment: @Samuel W Anderson does the microphone really work with the ios simulator?  I thought that's one of the hardware limitations ?

Comment: What could be the reason for my code to only receive 0 samples from the microphone in the simulator while it works on real hardware? I am using the AVAudioEngine and a tap on the input node. I also tried the mixer node but also received only zeros.
There is no error message / warning shown, it just does not work. What seems strane to me: Siri works in the simulator, so the microphone is correctly forwarded to the simulator but not to my app. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: The MacMini has no microphone.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think microphone works as of iOS 8.2. Here is link from Apple documentation that state this fact:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html

Look at the Hardware limitations section.

Comment: The microphone does not work, unless Siri is toggled (`Hardware` > `Siri` menu item).

Comment: Hi, the apple documentation you linked is not available anymore. I think the hardware limitations regarding the microphone are not holding anymore? In my app I use the AVAudioEngine with a tap on the input/mixer node but I only receive samples containing 0. When I use the same code on my real iPhone it works. Only the simulator does not work. It is also very strange that Siri works in the simulator, this means the sound signal is forwarded to the simulator, but not to my app. Do you have an idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

## The simulator this will automatically use your Mac's built-in microphone

`AVAudioRecorder` will record audio from the microphone. If you're using the simulator this will automatically use your Mac's built-in microphone, so you can test either on device or in the simulator.

### And if you are on a Mac mini without a microphone input?

Remember that there is a neat trick to record audio from your iPhone/iPad. You need a lightning cable or USB-C cable connected and enable your hardware device in the Utilities/Audio Devices settings:

[image: Audio Devices settings]

Click on enable: 
[image: enable]

This new audio input will be visible in your emulator! So now you can record in simulator even if your Mac hasn't got a microphone

It has been available forever I believe and I just verified, it works for the Mac mini 2018 and macOS Catalina 10.15.4 and Xcode Version 11.4.1.

It will be enough to trouble shoot your iOS apps, but there is a small caveat. By default you get the line out from your iOS device, so I could play music and my mac would receive it. So far so good.

However to properly access the mic you would need a third party app to bridge and make the mic available to the mini but this is not necessary to just troubleshoot the mic on the simulator. I hope I explained myself.